# How to use State Parameter instead of function parameters on VUEX

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, odata

I want to try different approach on how to use state parameters instead of function parameter, my code works perfectly fine, but my colleague said that I should use vue store as state parameter.

here's my vuex, in the fetchCoffeData I implemented searchQuery,origin,size, currentPage as function parameter

**getCoffeData.js**

```
import { OData } from '@odata/client'

const client = OData.New({
  metadataUri: `/data_coffe/arabica/coffe.xsodata/$metadata`
})

const module = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    config: {
      pagination: {
        currentPage: 1,
        inlineCount: 0,
        resultsPerPage: 50
      }
    },
    list: [
      /*
        {
          id: null,
          name: "",
         origin: "",
          origin_name: "",
         size: "",
          searchKey: ""
        }
         */
    ]
  }),
  mutations: {
    get_coffe_fetched(state, { inlineCount, result, currentPage }) {
      state.liste = result
      state.config.pagination.inlineCount = inlineCount
      state.config.pagination.currentPage = currentPage
    },
    get_coffe_updateCurrentPage: (state, currentPage) => {
      state.config.pagination.currentPage = currentPage
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateCurrentPage: ({ commit, state }, currentPage) => {
      commit('erezept_coffe_updateCurrentPage', currentPage)
      return state.config.pagination.currentPage
    },
    fetchCoffeData(
      { commit, state },
      // should be state parameters instead of function parameters
      { searchQuery,origin,size, currentPage }
    ) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let filter = `substringof('${searchQuery}', searchKey)`

        if (origin) {
          filter.property('origin').eq(origin)
        }
        if (size) {
          filter.property('size').eq(size)
        }

        const skip = (currentPage - 1) * state.config.pagination.resultsPerPage
        client
          .newRequest({
            collection: 'coffe',
            params: client
              .newParam()
              .filter(filter)
              .top(state.config.pagination.resultsPerPage)
              .skip(skip)
              .inlinecount(true)
          })
          .then(res => {
            commit('get_coffe_fetched', {
              inlineCount: res.d.__count,
              result: res.d.results,
              currentPage: currentPage
            })
            resolve()
          })
          .catch(() => reject())
      })
    }
  }
}

export default module
```

in the vue component, there are `VSelect` to filter coffe based on their size and origin.
**CoffeTable.vue**

```
<template>
<b-row>
  <b-form
     @submit.prevent="searchCoffeData">
     <b-form-group id="search-field">
       <b-form-input
          v-model="searchQuery"
           placeholder="Coffe Name"
       ></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-form>
   <b-table
      v-show="!loading"
      :items="pzn"
      :fields="conditionalTableFields"
      head-variant="light"
      @row-clicked="selectCoffeId"
   >
   ...
   </b-table>
   ...
    <VSelect
       v-model="origin"
       :options="originItems"
       placeholder="origin"
       label="label"
       value="value"
       @change="searchCoffeData"
     >
     </VSelect>
     <VSelect
       v-model="size"
       :options="sizeItems"
       placeholder="size"
       label="label"
       value="value"
       @change="searchCoffeData"
     >
     </VSelect>

</b-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1, 
      loading: false,
      size: null, 
      origin: null, 
      searchQuery: '', 
    }
  },
  computed: {
    coffe: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.data_coffe.arabica.coffe.list
      }
    },
     originItems() {
      const items = new Set(this.coffe.map(item => item.origin));
      return [...items].map(item => ({ label: item, value: item }));
    },
    sizeItems() {
      const items = new Set(this.coffe.map(item => item.size));
      return [...items].map(item => ({ label: item, value: item }));
    },
    selectedSizeValue() {
      return this.size ? this.size.value : null;
    },
    selectedOriginValue() {
      return this.origin ? this.origin.value : null;
    }
  },
 methods: {
    searchCoffeData() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.fetchCoffeData({
        searchQuery: this.searchQuery,
        origin: this.selectedOriginValue,
        size: this.selectedSizeValue,
        currentPage: this.currentPage,
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
    },
}
</script>
```

I should declare the parameter (searchQuery, origin, size, currentPage) in the state instead of function parameter like this.

```
const module = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    config: {
      pagination: {
        currentPage: 1,
        inlineCount: 0,
        resultsPerPage: 15
      },
      filter: {
        origin: '',
        size: '',
        searchQuery: '',
      }
    },
    list: []
  }),
  mutations: {
    get_coffe_fetched(state, { inlineCount, result, currentPage }) {
      state.liste = result
      state.config.pagination.inlineCount = inlineCount
      state.config.pagination.currentPage = currentPage
    },
     get_coffe_updateCurrentPage: (state, currentPage) => {
      state.config.pagination.currentPage = currentPage
    },
    get_coffe_updateOrigin: (state, origin) => {
      state.config.filter.origin = origin
    },
    get_coffe_updateSize: (state, size) => {
      state.config.filter.size = size
    },
    get_coffe_updateSearchQuery: (state, searchQuery) => {
      state.config.filter.searchQuery = searchQuery
    },
 },
actions: {
  updateOrigin: ({ commit, state }, origin) => {
      commit('get_coffe_updateOrigin', origin)
      return state.config.filter.origin
    },
    updateSize: ({ commit, state }, size) => {
      commit('get_coffe_updateSize', size)
      return state.config.filter.size
    },
    updateSearchQuery: ({ commit, state }, searchQuery) => {
      commit('get_coffe_updateSearchQuery', searchQuery)
      return state.config.filter.searchQuery
    },
 }
```

but then I got stuck, what should I change in fetchCoffeData or where should I commit the mutations, and what should I change in searchCoffeData methods in vue component? I also should change the `sizeItems` and `OriginItems` should be a vuex getter,  `selectedSizeValue` and `selectedOriginValue` should be vuex state. I'm so confused, can anyone help?